# Universal jQuery and node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have an external .js file that is currently being used client side.  There are a bunch of functions in this file that I currently use formatted as such:

```
function test()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

What I am wanting to do is include this file and call these functions from a node.js script without having to change the syntax in the external file.  The external file is mostly jQuery.  I have tried several different approaches, all which have failed.  Most of what I'm seeing is telling me that this cannot be done because the syntax is incorrect and should be formatted as such:

```
exports.test = function()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

There has to be a way for me not to duplicate all of these functions so that the external file will continue to work client side as well as server side if I envoke it correctly.  HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me that the research you've already done is correct - you can't just re-use the file out of the box.

I'm not a seasoned Node developer so I am perhaps speaking out of turn, but that said - try using a Regular Expression find/replace to avoid the manual labor of adapting your file.  If you were to do this in JavaScript itself (how fitting), it may look like so:

```
var inputFile = 'function test()'; // ... your entire input file
var outputFile = inputFile.replace(/function *([a-z][_a-z0-9]*) *\((.*?)\)/i, 'exports.$1 = function($2)');
```

Plenty of good info on regular expressions here if you need it:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

You may have to tweak the regular expression for this replacement, and you may have to run several different replacement patterns to make your JavaScript execute in Node.  Again, my suggestion may be apsotasy to an experienced Node dev, but it's an idea.